# The credentials page never loads. Can't get API key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

I created a project and need to get the Google Maps API key.
Now when I go to "APIs & Services > Credentials" the page never loads and I can't get the key. I tried using different browsers and not using extensions as well as filling up the OAuth consent screen but with no luck.

Anyone else had this issue? If so please let me know.

EDIT: Plenty of console errors as [shown here](https://prnt.sc/mj2omq).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @MrUpsidown there are several threads that have a similar issue. Another user replied here saying they have the same problem but seems they deleted the comment. Google also recommends using StackOverflow and Google groups for troubleshooting for Bronze users as they don't provide support unless you're paying.

Comment: It works for me. What can I say... Did you try the community forums? If a Google website doesn't work properly, I don't know what we could do about it here.

Comment: A public issue has been created in Issue tracker issuetracker.google.com/124188941 about this. This issue has been fixed around 2019-02-12 04:26 UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It auddently started working. Was down for about two days. Closing question.

Comment: A public issue has been created in Issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/124188941 about this. This issue has been fixed around 2019-02-12 04:26 UTC.